# node-red redeploy flow using REST from within node-red

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red, dashdb

I have a node-red flow in bluemix that uses dash-db nodes also. So each time some dash db maintenance or some other reason, this db connection gets lost and all writes fail. When i redeploy, everything is fine again. Bluemix shows only logs of last few hours hence I am finding it very difficult to debug. Meanwhile i was thinking of doing an automatic redeploy after i detect this issue to avoid losing writes.
Can this be done using GET /flows followed by POST /flows in the same node-red app itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. it would be worth raising this as an issue with the dash-db nodes so the author can help address it - https://github.com/smchamberlin/node-red-nodes-cf-sqldb-dashdb
2. Yes, you can post back the flows. The full admin http api is documented here: http://nodered.org/docs/api/admin/ - have a look at the 'reload' option on `/flows`.